# Sorting human readable file sizes

Tags: linux, mac, unix, sorting

How can I sort a list using a human-readable file-size sort, numerical sort that takes size identifier (G,M,K) into account?  Can I sort "`du -sh`" output for example?

Problem:
Consider the problem of listing files/folders and sorting them by their size.  You can achieve that by running:

```
du -s * | sort -n
```

This lists the files/folders sorted by their sizes.  However the printed size value is in bytes (or megabytes, or gigabytes if you choose).

It would be desirable to be able to sort based on the human-readable values, so I can run something analogous to

```
du -sh * | <human-readable file sort>
```

And have 1.5GB folder shows up after 2.0M.

Comment: `du -hs * | sort -h` (from https://serverfault.com/a/156648/701616)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik, there's no standard command to do this.

There are various workarounds, which were discussed when the same question was asked over at Stack Overflow: [**How can I sort du -h output by size**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586033/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size)

Answer (score 38):

Use GNU coreutils >= 7.5:

du -hs * | sort -h

(Taken from this [serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/62411/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size/156648#156648))

[Man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#sort-invocation)

Edit: You can check your versions using `du --version` and `sort --version` if you are using the GNU versions. If you're using homebrew you may need to use `gdu` and `gsort`.

Comment: OSX doesn't have this option. You can use homebrew to `brew install coreutils` (which prepends all the coreutils commands with a 'g'). You can then do `gdu -hs * | gsort -h`.

Comment: Just to clarify @dsummersl's point: the `du -hs *` works fine on Mac OS X, but `sort -h` returns `sort: invalid option -- h`. 
One can also install the coreutils package via MacPorts as described [here](http://tunafreedolphin.com/?p=416).

Answer (score 3):

If you are just worried about files larger than 1MB, as it seems you are, you can use this command to sort them and use awk to convert the size to MB:

```
du -s * | sort -n | awk '{print int($1 / 1024)"M\t"$2}'
```

Again, this rounds the sizes to the nearest MB.  You can modify it converting to the unit of your choice.

Comment: This is similar to: `du -sm * | sort -n`.  `-s`/`-g` makes `du` output sizes in megabytes/gigabytes.

Comment: For MB you have to divide by 1024 more. So it will be `int($1 / (1024 * 1024))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one:

```
$ du -B1 | sort -nr | perl -MNumber::Bytes::Human=format_bytes -F'\t' -lane 'print format_bytes($F[0])."\t".$F[1]'
```

You might have to do a

```
$ cpan Number::Bytes::Human
```

first.

Answer (score 2):

This one handles filenames with whitespace or apostrophes, and works on systems which do not support `xargs -d` or `sort -h`:

```
du -s * | sort -n | cut -f2 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -I {} du -sh "{}"
```

which results in:

```
368K    diskmanagementd
392K    racoon
468K    coreaudiod
472K    securityd
660K    sshd
3.6M    php-fpm
```

Answer (score 1):

du -sk * | sort -n | awk '{ print $2 }' | while read f ; do du -sh "$f" ; done

Answer (score 1):

This command will sort by size in MB

```
du --block-size=MiB --max-depth=1 path | sort -n
```

Comment: That is already what the user is doing actually, he/she just didn't gave the example with MiB but mentioned about it.  What he/she is looking for is to be able to sort when using the `-h` flag to du.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here since I was trying to sort something else that combined MB and GB in the same output and I couldn't control it.

`$NF` is used since the `#GB` or `#MB` pattern was the last column in the output:

```
somecommand | \
gawk '{
  if ($NF ~ /[0-9\.]+GB/) 
    { a=gensub(/([0-9\.]+)(GB)/,"\\1","g",$NF); \
    printf "%sMB\n", a*1024} \
  else {print $NF} 
}' | \
sort -n
```

Explanation of the awk command:

`if ($NF ~ /[0-9\.]+GB/)`

if the last column matches the regex pattern which contains a digit or a `.` one or more times followed by `GB`

`{ a=gensub(/([0-9\.]+)(GB)/,"\\1","g",$NF); \`

then set variable `a` to the digit portion of each line which matches the same regex pattern in the same last column (`$NF`)

`printf "%sMB\n", a*1024} \`

after setting `a`, use `printf` to format the output as `${a*1024}MB`

`else {print $NF}`

otherwise just print the last column

`sort -n`

use numeric sort on the output

---

**example**

```
echo "4MB\n5GB\n420MB\n420GB\n1024MB\n1GB" | \                                                                                                                                 23:43:06 (EMP-2653/package-upgrades) Ø M
gawk '{
  if ($NF ~ /[0-9\.]+GB/)
    { a=gensub(/([0-9\.]+)(GB)/,"\\1","g",$NF); \
    printf "%sMB\n", a*1024} \
  else {print $NF}
}' | \
sort -n
```

I'm sure there's a way to reuse the regex pattern so I'm only performing the match once and replacing in place, but I don't know how to do that yet :)